# Why do some statements generate warnings in "Release" but not in "Debug" mode compilation with GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

I am using gcc to compile some C++ code, and while the code compiles fine when using "Debug" configuration, it emits warnings in "Release" configuration. The only difference in the compile options is:

"Debug": `g++ -O0 -g3 ...`

"Release": `g++ -O3 ...`

The message I see in the "Release" build:

```
../src/xml.cpp: In static member function ‘static Z<char>* XML::ReadToZ(const char*, XMLTransform*, XMLTransformData*)’:
../src/xml.cpp:5034: warning: ignoring return value of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
../src/xml.cpp:5041: warning: ignoring return value of ‘size_t fread(void*, size_t, size_t, FILE*)’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

The relevant two statements are:

```
/* 5034 */ fread((*y).operator char *(),1,S,fp);
/* 5041 */ fread(yy.operator char *(),1,S,fp);
```

**Why is there a difference in warnings?**

Comment: Why does it matter? Check the return value.

Comment: @chris - First of all, it matters b/c I'm interested in actually *understanding* the problem, and not just *bypassing* it. Secondly, this is not my code, but a part of a package that was downloaded from the web, so I'm reluctant to change it.

Comment: It's not really bypassing a problem to heed a compiler warning that makes logical sense. If it fails to read what you expect, you have no way of knowing. Being code written by someone else, they should have put in the effort to make it robust and not give warnings when compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bug report at the [GCC bugzilla](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25509) about this behaviour. Try adding --no-warn-unused-result to your "Release" profile.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, this is "deep". This report did put things in context. I did not read too deeply into the bug report thread, but there are some thoughtful arguments there.

Comment: Using that flag is a bad idea. The problem with most buggy C programs is unchecked results. You **do not want to hide** these problems.

Answer (score 2):

Some warnings are generated based on "flow analysis", which is something the compiler does during certain optimisation steps.

You probably should fix those warnings!

Comment: Thanks. This is not my code, but a part of a package that was downloaded from the web, so I'm reluctant to change it. The strange thing is that the two `fread()` calls are located in the two branches of an `if-else` statement, so one of them is supposed to be evaluated (unless the while `if` is optimized out, but this does not seem to be the case). Then, immediately after the `fread()`-s there are `fclose()` statements. Why there is no warning on these (or any other stdlib function call out of the thousands that are not being checked)?

Comment: @ysap, Because `fread` has the attribute attached to it. You never know what you're getting from input, so it warns you when you don't check.